# Accessing JavaScript var's each char and adding back-slash n to divide string in 2 lines

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to divide my string in 2 lines if string is greater than 15 characters, so i am finding a space after 15 char and putting /n to string so that when var gets printed it should get printed in 2 lines. 
following is my JavaScript code. its not working, please if anyone can help.
Thankyou

```
  var name = row.product_name;
                    var val = 15;
                    var output;
                    var flag = false;
                    console.log(name[0]);
                    for(i=0; i<row.product_name.length; i++)
                    {      
                        if(i > val)
                        {
                            if(name[i] == ' ')
                            {
                                name[i] = "/n";
                                flag = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if(flag)
                        {
                            val = val + 15;
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: *"its not working"* is not a proper technical problem statement and tells us next to nothing about what does or doesn't happen, errors thrown etc. Take some time to read through [ask]

Comment: you got the idea what i am trying to do, if you know JS, you should know why its not working, and else wise i am also asking if you can give solution to my problem in any other way or logic.

Comment: Code problems aren't that straightforward. As per [ask] it is expected that you detail your issues with sufficient information to make them clear and specific.That statement could mean anything from *"nothing happens"* to *"\n is in wrong place"* ...we don't know unless you tell us. And errors thrown are big clues, if any exist

Comment: @charlietfl and for your information there is no error, its not putting the /n in string and still printing all the string in single line, what i wrote in the question earlier too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can't work because javascript strings are immutable, so you can't reassign name[i]. You have to use replace, slice, split, or other operations on the whole string

```js
var myString = "jsdjposjgiohg squg oiq oih osqdh uh hsquv hup h opsdqh voph";
myStringA=myString.split(" ");
var newString="";

var n=0;
for (var i=0;i<myStringA.length;i++){
 n+=myStringA[i].length;
  if (n>15){
   n=0;
    newString+=myStringA[i]+"\n";   
  }else{
   newString+=myStringA[i]+" ";
  }  
}
  console.log(newString);
```

Comment: can you please type code how to fix it? that will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in javascript so you need to put the changes in a new variable

Also the newline character is `\n` not `/n`

```
var name = row.product_name;
                var val = 15;
                var output = "";
                var flag = false;
                console.log(name[0]);
                for(i=0; i<row.product_name.length; i++)
                {   
                    output += name[i]   
                    if(i > val)
                    {
                        if(name[i] == ' ')
                        {
                            output[i] = "\n";
                            flag = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if(flag)
                    {
                        val = val + 15;
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: i checked, the problem is still there.